# I am trying to find clickable/non clickable inks using mentioned code and print it in console

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

This code is extracting links from given URLs. Want to chalk out clickable and non clickable links from the extracted links.

```
from selenium import webdriver       
import time    

ccount=0   
ncount=0

URL = input('Enter URL: ')

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

URL = input('Enter URL: ')

driver.get(URL)

time.sleep(2)

ids = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@href]')

for a in ids:

    print(a.get_attribute('href'))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific/ predefined method for clickable link in Selenium, we have to perform click operation and validate any UI elements/ element attributes

Loop over the clickableCount array

```
1. Save the current web url
2. Click on the link
3. Check whether URL changed or not and continue until end
```